# How can I change the state in the render?

Tags: reactjs

I get an array of paragraphs, each paragraph having a chapter number. I keep the chapter number in state.

And I made a starting value of 1. Because I want them to start reading from the first chapter.

The problem starts when there are certain paragraphs without any chapter. And when such a case happens, I want to present everything.

So I check in render whether the array of "chapters" is empty and if so I want to change the state that the chapter number will be 0 (then later it is set that if it is 0 show everything.)

And I got an error message -

> cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

I read and saw that it is not worth changing this in render. But I do not see another place that can put it because in render I get the array from the give database.

```
 let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>loading...</em></p>
            : ShiurId.renderForecastsTable(this.state.forecasts, this.state.currentChapter);

        const allChapters = [... new Set(this.state.forecasts.filter(num => num.chapter != 0 && num.chapter != null ).map(data => data.chapter))];

        if (!this.state.loading) {

            if (allChapters.length <= 1) {
                if (this.state.currentChapter == 1) {

                    this.stateChange();
                }
            }
        }
```

```
   stateChange= () => {
        this.setState(({ currentChapter }) => ({ currentChapter: 0 }))
    };
```

Does anyone have any advice on where to change the state?

Comment: You are supposed to handle this kind of logic inside of the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method or in a `useEffect` callback. Render() should only look at the current data and display appropriate UI state, without doing any state changes itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, putting state changes directly inside `render` can cause recursivity, but you can put it inside `componentDidMount` (If you want it to happen only once)
or `componentDidUpdate` (If you want it to happen every time there is any change state or props), like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>loading...</em></p>
        : ShiurId.renderForecastsTable(this.state.forecasts, this.state.currentChapter);

    const allChapters = [... new Set(this.state.forecasts.filter(num => num.chapter != 0 && num.chapter != null ).map(data => data.chapter))];

    if (!this.state.loading) {

        if (allChapters.length <= 1) {
            if (this.state.currentChapter == 1) {

                this.stateChange();
            }
        }
    }
}
```